# .NET Windows Forms Databinding - Bind to Relation Parent

Tags: winforms, data-binding

Maybe I am asking the wrong question, nobody seems to have this issue, but I think it's not so rare. Maybe I don't know the right words in english.

I have a DataSet with a DataTable A. Some columns contain values that are IDs, and table B contains the texts for these IDs. I want to show table A in a list (DataGridView). For the columns that contain ID values, I want to show the text from table B.

So, for one row in B, there are many rows in A. This makes B the parent in the foreign key relation and A the child. And that's the problem: I don't know how to enter this as a binding definition in Windows Forms. The opposite direction is easy, I can enter the BindingSource for table A as the DataSource of another BindingSource, enter the Relation Name as DataMember and I get all child rows.

But when I create a dependent BindingSource, I can't enter the name of a relation where the DataSource is the child, that gives me an error.

I created a workaround with a computed column in the DataTable A. There I can write PARENT(relation).NAME. Of course that doesn't work, when I enter it directly as DataMember.

So, am I stuck with that workaround, or is there some magic construct that allows data binding to a relation parent?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244085/bindingsource-and-parent-datarelation) that proposed to reverse the relation. I'd hate to do that. Is there really no other way?